# How can I efficiently and uniformly sample the set of vertices a fixed edge-wise distance away from a chosen vertex?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm

I have a large graph $G$, which may be either directed or undirected.  How would I use `DepthFirstScan[]` or `BreadthFirstScan[]` to efficiently and uniformly sample the set of vertices a fixed shortest distance of $D$ away from some vertex $v_i \in V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a graph and a distance `d`:

```
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[1000, 1]];

d = 5
```

Find the distance of a vertex (e.g. vertex 300) to all others:

```
distances = GraphDistance[g, 300];
```

Sample `k` vertices from those with distance `d` from 300:

```
RandomSample[
 Pick[VertexList[g], distances, d],
 k
]
```

Comment: other variance could be: Reap[CheckAbort[
   BreadthFirstScan[g, 300, 
    "DiscoverVertex" -> ((If[#3 > 5, Abort[]]; 
        If[#3 == d, Sow[#1]]) &)], "Done"]][[2, 1]] or Complement[AdjacencyList[g, 300, d], AdjacencyList[g, 300, d - 1]]

Comment: @halmir Why don't you post it as another answer?  Instead of Abort[] I'd use Return[] (after wrapping the whole thing in a function).  Or use two-argument Return. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way to extract vertices:

```
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[1000, 1]];
d = 5;
```

1. Szabolcs suggestion

   ```
   distances = GraphDistance[g, 300];
   set1 = Pick[VertexList[g], distances, d];
   ```
2. using BreadthFirstScan

   ```
   set2 = Reap[
    CheckAbort[
     BreadthFirstScan[g, 300, "DiscoverVertex" -> ((If[#3 > 5, Abort[]]; 
     If[#3 == d, Sow[#1]]) &)], "Done"]][[2, 1]];
   ```

   with Return[]

   ```
   set3 = Reap[
    BreadthFirstScan[g, 300, "DiscoverVertex" -> ((If[#3 > 5, Return[]]; 
    If[#3 == d, Sow[#1]]) &)]][[2, 1]];
   ```
3. using AdjacencyList:

   ```
   set4 = Complement[AdjacencyList[g, 300, d], AdjacencyList[g, 300, d - 1]];
   ```

Compare results:

```
In[271]:= Sort[set1] == Sort[set2] == Sort[set3] == Sort[set4]
Out[271]= True
```